# Dependency tracking is not working after azure function app deployment

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights, asp.net-core-3.1

Currently have an azure function v3 in .netcore 3.1 with the following host.json

```
    {
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "http": {
      "maxConcurrentRequests": 300
    }
  },
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "EnableDependencyTracking": true,
      "DependencyTrackingOptions": {
        "enableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Things work fine(It track dependency) while running locally but after function app deployment it doesn't track SQL or HTTP or any other dependency.

[image]

Has anyone run into this issue before or have any advice on how to maintain default dependency tracking?

Answer (score 0):

Verify Default Loglevel should be "Information" for dependency tracking

Comment: Any reference to docs stating this?